# Remote Logging for Syslog

Tags: linux, syslog

I'm trying to set up syslog to accept remote logging. I already have changed the config file and set up the syslogd with "-r m 0" to accept remote logging. Now i need to change the /etc/services file. I know it needs to be:
something 514/udp
something 514/tcp

Should the something be syslog, Syslog, syslogd, or Syslogd. I'm not sure but I don't have root to test them so I'm having to send a request to get it done and would like it done right the first time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`syslog 514/udp`

but in standard /etc/services it is already set...